# series name and data for highcharts assigned via loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts, javascript-objects

I am trying to loop a list of JSON objects and assign some keys as the name of the highcharts series and the convergencesData as the list of data. I have placed a static chart example with what I am trying to achieve for the series data of the chart. I have given an example of my JSON schema as well if that helps.

I also have a jsfiddle as well [static expected chart jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mastarke/jkbL4xde/23/)

THIS IS MY STATIC EXPECTED OUTPUT CHART:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'mychart'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'mychart'
    },

    xAxis: {
    categories: [
      'r611.10i',
      'r622.15i',
      'r633.7i',
      '701.10i',
      '702.11i',
    ],
    crosshair: true
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Convergence'
    }
  },
    
    series: [{
        name: 'tc1',
        data: [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5]
    }, {
        name: 'tc2',
        data: [2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5]
    }, {
        name: 'tc3',
        data: [3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5]
    }],

    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            }
        }]
    }

});
```

```css
#container {
 min-width: 310px;
 max-width: 800px;
 height: 400px;
 margin: 0 auto
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

THIS IS MY JSON SCHEMA DATA:

```
var data1 = {
  "TestBedGeneralInfo": {
    "TestCaseName": ['tc1','tc2', 'tc3', 'tc4', 'tc5']
  },

  "TestCaseData": {
    "tc1": {
      "convergenceData":1.1
    },
    "tc2": {
      "convergenceData":1.2
    },
    "tc3": {
      "convergenceData": 1.3
    },
    "tc4": {
        "convergenceData":1.4
    },
    "tc5": {
       "convergenceData":1.5
    }
  }
}
var data2 = {
  "TestBedGeneralInfo": {
    "TestCaseName": ['tc1','tc2', 'tc3', 'tc4', 'tc5']
  },

  "TestCaseData": {
    "tc5": {
      "convergenceData":2.5
    },
    "tc4": {
      "convergenceData":2.4
    },
    "tc3": {
      "convergenceData": 2.3
    },
    "tc2": {
        "convergenceData":2.2
    },
    "tc1": {
       "convergenceData":2.1
    }
  }
}
var data3 = {
  "TestBedGeneralInfo": {
    "TestCaseName": ['tc1','tc2', 'tc3', 'tc4', 'tc5']
  },

  "TestCaseData": {
    "tc4": {
      "convergenceData":3.4
    },
    "tc5": {
      "convergenceData":3.5
    },
    "tc1": {
      "convergenceData": 3.1
    },
    "tc2": {
        "convergenceData":3.2
    },
    "tc3": {
       "convergenceData":3.3
    }
  }
}
```

HERE ARE SOME LOOPS IVE TRIED:

```
var tc_name_list = ['tc1','tc2', 'tc3', 'tc4', 'tc5']
var tc_data = [data1,data2,data3]
for(objNum=0; objNum < tc_data.length; objNum++) {
     var tc_temp_name;
    console.log('objNum is ' + objNum)
    for(i=0; i < tc_name_list.length; i++) {
        tc_temp_name = tc_name_list[i];
        console.log('tc_temp_name is ' + tc_temp_name + '  :->' + tc_data[objNum]['TestCaseData'][tc_temp_name]['convergenceData'])
        var output = tc_data[objNum]
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
var data = [data1, data2, data3],
    categories = ['tc1', 'tc2', 'tc3', 'tc4', 'tc5'],
    finalData = {},
    series;

categories.forEach(function (cat) {
  if (!finalData[cat]) {
    finalData[cat] = {
      name: cat,
      data: []
    }
  }

  data.forEach(function(dataElem) {
    finalData[cat].data.push(dataElem.TestCaseData[cat].convergenceData);
  });
});

series = Object.keys(finalData).map(i => finalData[i]);
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3jo2z8kf/

Comment: Thank you very much. This is extremely helpful. One question I have is in my first example the categories list is set like this `categories = ['tc1', 'tc2', 'tc3', 'tc4', 'tc5'],` and i think you use  `series = Object.keys(finalData).map(i => finalData[i]);` to order it. but how could i get this to work if the categories were not numbers but were like this `categories = ['tc-A', 'tc-B', 'tc-C', 'tc-D', 'tc-E'],` I put another jsfiddle here to explain more what I mean. https://jsfiddle.net/mastarke/gwj9stym/3/

Comment: sorry i figured out my question. it does work with `categories = ['tc-A', 'tc-B', 'tc-C', 'tc-D', 'tc-E']`  https://jsfiddle.net/mastarke/gwj9stym/6/